# An ordinary differential equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

While I was working on a variational problem, I met this equation as its Euler-Lagrange equation, but I cannot solve it:
$ x= \frac{af'(x)}{\sqrt{1+af'(x)^{2}}} + \frac{bf'(x)}{\sqrt{1+bf'(x)^{2}}} \ (a\neq b) $.

Comment: For completeness and readers in the future, I would include the Lagrangian, since going backwards to find it is non-trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve it parametrically as follows:  Write 
$$
x(t) = \frac{at}{\sqrt{1+at^2}}+\frac{bt}{\sqrt{1+bt^2}}
$$
and
$$
y(t) = c - \frac{\sqrt{1+at^2}+\sqrt{1+bt^2}}{\sqrt{1+at^2}\sqrt{1+bt^2}}
$$
where $c$ is a constant.  Then this gives the general solution as $c$ varies.

If you want an explicit relation between $x$ and $y$, you can eliminate $t$, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: To see what the solution looks like: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xsuj2he8ts

Comment: @WillieWong:  Thanks!  That's a neat demo.  

FYI:  The solution curve is algebraic, of course.  It might be worth mentioning that it is an algebraic curve in the $xy$-plane of degree 8 in general.

Comment: Can you explain that final comment? I think I can work out why the curve is algebraic, but how did you constrain the degree to be 8?

Comment: We have the following polynomial relations among $x, y, t,  u = \sqrt{1+at^2}$ and $v = \sqrt{1+bt^2}$: $u^2 - (1+at^2)=0$, $v^2 - (1+bt^2)=0$, $uvx - but - avt = 0$,  $uvy - cuv+u+v=0$.  Eliminate $u,v,t$ by computing a "plex" Groebner basis of the ideal generated by the left sides of these equations.  The first element of the basis is a rather complicated polynomial of degree $8$ in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You might find this [graph](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/problems/c123.png) of the curve in the case $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=3$ interesting.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  It's quite possible that, for certain values of $a$ and $b$, the polynomial of degree 8 will be reducible, so that there are solutions of lower degree, but I think that, for the generic values of $a$ and $b$, the curve will be irreducible of degree $8$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, that's what the Groebner basis says.  If, for example, $b=a$, then you get $ \left( a{c}^{2}-2\,acy+a{y}^{2}+{x}^{2} \right)  \left( a{c}^{
2}-2\,acy+a{y}^{2}+{x}^{2}-4\,a \right)$.

Comment: And [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/problems/C10.gif) is an animation of the curve for $a=1, c=0$ with varying $b$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: One thing you can say is that, when $a\not=b$, the curve $\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$ is an algebraic curve of genus $1$:  This is because its parametrized as $(x,y)=\bigl(at/u+bt/v, \ c-(u+v)/(uv)\bigr)$ where $t$, $u$, and $v$ satisfy the relations $$u^2-at^2-1=v^2-bt^2-1=0,$$ so that this $tuv$-curve is the intersection of two quadrics in $3$-space that are in (projectively) general position whenever $ab(a{-}b)\not=0$, so that they define a space curve of genus $1$ and degree $4$.  Consequently, I think that, whenever $ab(a{-}b)\not=0$, the $xy$-curve of degree $8$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 5):

Set $p:=f'(x)$ and
$$
\Phi(p)=\Phi_{a,b}:=\frac{ap}{\sqrt{1+ap^2}}+\frac{bp}{\sqrt{1+bp^2}}.
$$
The differential equation you wrote  can be rewritten as
$$
x=\Phi(p).
$$
If we could invert $\Phi$, then we could write
$$
f'(x)= p=\Phi^{-1}(x).
$$
For $a, b>0$ the function $\Phi$ seems to be increasing. The animation below depicts the graphs of $\Phi_{1,t}$ for $t\in [0,6]$

[image]

It already shows that  the solution blows up in finite time. (Here I think of $x$ as time.)

The next animation depicts $\phi_{1,t}$  for $t=-1..0$ and you can see that the injectivity of $\Phi$ is lost  for some values of $t$.

[image]

**Remark.**  Here is an animation of the curve  described by Robert Bryant for $a=1$ and $b\in [-0.1,0.2]$, $t\in[-3,3]$

[image]